# Parametrizing markings

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose I define a style adding some marks, e.g. as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        mymarks/.style = {
            postaction = {
                decorate,
                decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow[red]{>};}},
            },
        },
    ]
    \draw[mymarks] (0, 0) -- (1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How to parametrize such a style? Namely, how to make the color 'red' a customizable parameter? Of course a simple direct way is to use the key value for that and write `\arrow[#1]` and `mymarks=red`. But what if the key value is already used for something else and the color parameter should be optional anyway?

One idea is to define `mymarks/color/.store in = \param` and write `\arrow[\param]` and `\draw[mymarks/color=red, mymarks]`, but then I would need to make a global macro for every such parameter myself.

Another idea is to do something define `mymarks/color/.initial = red` and use it as `\arrow[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mymarks/color}]`. But is there some way to make a local shortcut like `\path let` when defining the postaction so I don't have to write `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mymarks/color}` all the time if the value is used several times?

Is there some better way to do such parametrization?

Comment: `\def~#1{\pkgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/my marks/#1}}` and then you can use `~{color}` instead. But is it really so bad to use a long macro name inside a style you define and you only have to write once?

Comment: You can always opt in for more arguments.  `\tikzset{mymark/.style 2 args=...}` or even `style n args`.  Of course the tikzpert way to to that is `every mymark style/.style={red}` and then `\arrow[every mymark style/.try]`.

Comment: For the `\path let` part, consider using `\pgfkeysgetvalue`.  Or you can always define shortcut `a1/.style={every mymark style.try}`. So length shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can define a macro that's just a wrapper for `\pgfkeysvalueof`, the shortest “macro” that's readily available is `~` (which is a) an active character and b) usually is used for an nonbreaking space). Inside an arrow tip marking the nonbreaking space won't be needed. Thus, you can say:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  /pgf/decoration/tilde shortcut/.code = 
    \def~##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mymarks/##1}},
  mymarks/.default = ,
  mymarks/.style = {
    postaction = {
      decorate,
      decoration = {
        markings, tilde shortcut,
        mark = at position .5 with {\arrow[~{color}]{>}},
      }
    }
  },
  mymarks/color/.initial=red,
]
\draw[mymarks] (0, .3) -- (1, .5);
\draw[mymarks/color=green, mymarks] (0, 0) -- (1, .2) node[right]{x~y};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you can see, the `~` has its normal definition when we're back to the `node`.

But since you only define the `mymarks` style once I don't think you  really need to use a shortcut. (Although, maybe

```
\newcommand*\mymarksvo[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mymarks/#1}}
```

is short and unique enough?)

---

I'd go even further. Here we define a `mymarks` key that takes optionally a list of keys/values and applies them in the `/tikz/mymarks` name space:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mymarks/.default = ,
  mymarks/.style = {
    postaction = {
      decorate,
      decoration = {
        markings,
        /utils/exec=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/mymarks}{#1},
        my mark/.style = {
          mark = at position ########1 with {%
            \arrow[style/.expand twice/.expand once =
              \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mymarks/style}
            ]{>}
          }
        },
        my mark/.list/.expand twice/.expand once=
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mymarks/pos}
      },
    },
  },
  mymarks/pos/.initial=.5,
  mymarks/style/.initial=red,
]
\draw[mymarks] (0, .3) -- (1, .5);
\draw[
  mymarks={
    pos={.2, .4, ..., .8},
    style={scale=2, rotate=-90}
  }
] (0, 0) -- (1, .2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This way you don't need to (but still be able to) do `mymarks/pos = …` or `mymarks/style = …` in addition to `mymarks` itself and you can just say

```
mymarks = {pos = …, style = …}
```

(The `/tikz/style` key used in `\arrow` is just defined as `style/.style = {#1}`, i.e. it would be just the same as just using `#1` however we now can do something with the `#1` before it is used which we otherwise couldn't. In this case: expansion.)

Our own `/tikz/mymarks/style` key (which is **not** a style but a value-key) is used somewhat unusual. (We can use `style/.append = …` to append keys to this value so we can almost use it in the same way would use an  actual style.)

---

A proper style is probably better. We define a `/tikz/mymarks/every arrow` style which we now need to either overwrite

```
mymarks = {every arrow/.style = …}
```

or append to if we don't want to lose previous settings:

```
mymarks = {every arrow/.append style = …}
```

PGF/TikZ and packages/libraries that are built upon it usually also define an `arrows` key that appends to `every arrow`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  /pgf/decoration/mymarks/.style = {
    mark = at position #1 with {\arrow[mymarks/every arrow]{>}}},
  mymarks/.default = ,
  mymarks/.style = {
    postaction = {
      decorate,
      decoration = {
        markings,
        /utils/exec=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/mymarks}{#1},
        mymarks/.list/.expand twice/.expand once=
          \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mymarks/pos}
      },
    },
  },
  mymarks/pos/.initial=.5,
  mymarks/every arrow/.style=red,
  mymarks/arrows/.style={every arrow/.append style={#1}}
]
\draw[mymarks] (0, .3) -- (1, .5);
\draw[
  mymarks={
    pos={.2, .4, ..., .8},
    arrows={scale=2, rotate=-90}% still red
  }
] (0, 0) -- (1, .2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

Now `.expand twice/.expand once` is somewhat clunky, we can define our own `.expand thrice` handler … or a handler that uses the value of the given key … or an even shorter handler for this:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/handlers}{
  .expand thrice/.code=%
    \pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.expand twice/.expand once={#1}},
  .value/.code=%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}\pgfkeys@temp
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call\expandafter{\pgfkeys@temp},%
  .tikz value/.code=\pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.value=/tikz/#1},
  .../.code=\pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.value=/tikz/mymarks/#1},
}
\makeatother
```

Now you can do any one of these:

```
my mark/.list/.expand thrice = \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/mymarks/pos}
my mark/.list/.value = /tikz/mymarks/pos
my mark/.list/.tikz value = mymarks/pos
my mark/.list/... = pos
```

Though, similar to `~` I'd define `...` only local.

---

But we can do drive this even further …

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/handlers}{
  .value/.code=%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{#1}\pgfkeys@temp
    \expandafter\pgfkeys@exp@call\expandafter{\pgfkeys@temp}%
    % this is equivalent to:
    % \pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.expand once=\pgfkeys@temp}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  /pgf/decoration/my mark/.style = {
    /utils/exec=\edef\mymarkscounter{\the\numexpr\mymarkscounter+1\relax},
    mark/.expanded = at position #1 with {\noexpand\arrow[
        mymarks/every arrow,
        mymarks/arrow \mymarkscounter/.try
      ]{>}
    }% expanded is needed since "mark" only collects
  },
  mymarks/.default = ,
  mymarks/.style = {
    postaction = {
      decorate,
      decoration = {
        markings,
        /utils/exec=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/mymarks}{#1}\def\mymarkscounter{0},
        my mark/.list/.value=/tikz/mymarks/pos
      }
    }
  },
  mymarks/pos/.initial=.5, mymarks/every arrow/.style=red,
  % to be on the safe site we use the full path so that we can do
  % \tikzset{mymarks/arrows=…}
  % where we don't want to reder to /tikz/every arrow
  mymarks/arrows/.style={/tikz/mymarks/every arrow/.append style={#1}}
]
\draw[mymarks] (0, .3) -- (1, .5);
\draw[
  mymarks={
    pos={.2, .4, ..., .8},
    arrows = {scale = 2, rotate = -90},
    arrow 3/.style = blue,
    arrow 2/.style = {green, > = {Stealth[round]}}
  }
] (0, 0) -- (1, .2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```